# Kafka broadcasting of events and wait for the asynchronous responses

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices

I have set of microservices (MS<sub>1</sub> , MS<sub>2</sub>...MS<sub>n</sub>) all communicating with each other using Kafka messages.

I now need to have a functionality where one microservice (lets say MS<sub>1</sub>) has to call an external service at certain frequency.

But before calling this external service MS<sub>1</sub> has to fetch relevant data from all microsevices (lets say MS<sub>2</sub>,..., MS<sub>N</sub>).

MS<sub>1</sub> broadcasts the event for data collection . All microservices who are interested submit the data in a response event to MS<sub>1</sub>.

Since Kafka communication is asynchronous , there is no way for MS<sub>1</sub> to know whether the data has been submitted by all the microservices or not. I don't want to keep a track of all the number of microservices which should submit the data. Because this sender count can change dynamically and MS<sub>1</sub> should be agnostic of that.

One way is to have two schedules:

1. Scheduled job for data collection.
2. Scheduled job for consolidation of data and sending it to the external service.

Is there any other way to handle this situation?

Comment: What if MSx does not respond? What if MSy responds but too late?

Comment: How would you know if you've gotten all responses without "tracking"?

Comment: @OneCricketeer tracking makes MS1 bound to all the services and i have keep changing the services to be tracked in future if some  new service wants to send data or old service don't want to. Wanted to avoid that

Comment: Use an orchestrator like temporal.io instead of Kafka for such use cases.

Comment: no way to know if all services have responded, but you can use a timeout and use all messages that arrive during that window. if a ms cannot respond on time, bad luck, but since all of them run async, that is most probably not a big of a problem. all will probably respond during the next schedule. (if i understood correctly, what you mean by using 2 schedules also ends up in the same solution as using a simple timeout)